# why dbtype int32 is the same as int64 hier

Tags: c#, switch-statement, dbtype

Please, I want to know why the question has the answer false.

[image: The question I want to be answered]

Comment: What second option? If you want to ask something, post the relevant information in the question itself.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos He has a screenshot of a piece of code.

Comment: @xanatos I noticed, that still makes this a bad question. Posting the code is *not* hard.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `false` because there is no `case DbType.Int64` anywhere in that code, so the `default: return null` inside the `switch` is used.

I'll add that the [`DbType`](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Data/System/Data/dbtype.cs) is an `enum`... If we look at its values (the link is to its source code), we will see that `DbType.Int64 == 12`, and that there are no other enum constants with value 12, so there can't even be the case of, for example, `DbType.Int64 == 12 == DbType.Int32`, because there is NO other enum constant with value 12.

Code sample: http://rextester.com/BSUP55337 and https://dotnetfiddle.net/dHOrNM .

The three correct responses are No, Yes, No.

Comment: thanks for the answer.this is logic and makes sense but the tools that im using contains a lot of wrong answers. this is confusing even though that i have also tested it.and sorry for the screen shot.